# generated-source folder not created in Java project

Tags: java, playframework, target, generated

I created a java project using `sbt`. While I was trying to use an Immutable class using @Value.Immutable annotation I noticed that `generated-source` folder is not created. Instead, I see the structure :

[image]

I also updated `Build, Execution and Deployment` section, ran `sbt clean` then `sbt compile`. I still don't see the generated-sources folder.

[image]

Any naive mistake I am making?
Should scala target directory even be created because its a java play framework project?